# Origin of the expression "you can't make chicken salad out of chicken something else"

Tags: etymology, sports

I discovered this expression:

> You can't make chicken salad out of chicken *something else*

I heard this expression from one of the NBA basketball TV commentators on Fox Sports Oklahoma, who uses it in the affirmative, and uses *something else* instead *shit*. He uses it when a basketball player manages to score from a play situation that didn't look good at all:

> The player made chicken salad out of chicken *something else*.

I would like to know what is the origin of the expression and where does it originate from. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this just a variant of *"you can't polish a turd"*?

Answer (score 4):

An outline of the origins, uses and etymology of the phrase and its relation(s) can be found [by Barry Popik](http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/you_cant_make_chicken_salad_out_of_chicken_shit). A summary:

> The expressive flip side to “chicken salad” is “chicken feathers” (a euphemism for “chicken shit"). A difference “between chicken salad and chicken feathers” is cited in print in 1924; “like chicken salad compares with chicken feathers” is cited from 1930.

Answer (score 0):

The first time I heard the saying was in 2007, when Casey Printers (quarterback) was cut from the NFL's Kansas City Chiefs.  "You want me to make chicken salad out of chicken-sh."

Comment: That is quite an interesting anecdote; however, the etymology goes much beyond that.